# Blazor Server - Quill.js - Rich Text Editor - Max Length and Counter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, quill

I'm creating a Blazor Server application that is using Quill.js Rich Text Editor, now it works fine on me, but the client is required to set a limit on the Rich Text Editors, on my application, I have multiple rich text editors which the client wants a different maximum length and also with a counter, I'm trying to search it on the internet, but none suit the answer that I want, now what I see, Blazor will do nothing for this and it will be in Javascript or Jquery, but I don't know what to do, I want to try the Blazored Rich Text Editor, but It has a limit when it comes to design, which is a requirement on my application, I tried also the Syncfusion but to use their components without watermark or to use the full function, we need to pay for a license, and our company won't pay for a function that we can only use on a few projects. So what we can have is the quill.js, but yeah I'm having a problem setting limitations on our Rich Text Editor.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks and regards